# Can Initial node have two processes at the same time?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Hi I am working with UML diagrams and I am wondering if  one class can have two processes at the same time at initial node?
[image: Here the some thing I began with, is it right or I should use if else statement?]

Answer (score 2):

Sure it can. Whether or not concurrent processes are possible is dependent on the operating system and the language you use. But from a pure object perspective there is nothing hindering you from modeling concurrent processes for single classes.

Note that even rather old languages like Modula-2 (from the 80s) support concurrent processes as native language construct.

Answer (score 0):

You can also model something like in the following schema. There is an implicit fork at beginning and an implicit join at CallOperation5.

It is easier "to draw", the counter part is that your readers have to know UML well.
[image]

Comment: That's not correct. There is no "implicit fork"! Only one token is under way and it is undetermined as to what way it will go. Look up the UML "norm" (grin).

Comment: :) I looked : "An ExecutableNode shall not execute until all incoming ControlFlows (if any) are offering tokens. That is, there is an
implicit join on the incoming Control Flows. Specific kinds of ExecutableNodes may have additional prerequisites that
must be satisfied before the node can execute."

Comment: It's not the join, it's the initial split. That is ONLY done by a fork node. Only that will create multiple tokens from a single one.

Comment: Read p. 385 Initial Node. There's only a single token placed in it. And a token will ONLY be multiplied by a fork (read on next page).

Comment: in fact, there is an implicit fork : When an ExecutableNode completes an execution, the control token representing that execution is removed from the
ExecutableNode and control tokens are offered on all outgoing ControlFlows of the ExecutableNode. That is, there is an
implicit fork of the flow of control from the ExecutableNode to its outgoing ControlFlows. But for an Excutable node and the initial one is not an executable. So I need to correct the answer on this point.

Comment: Found it. You are right. I stand corrected. But do I like that definition?

Comment: You should put that reference in your answer. And then we can remove this dispute...

Comment: And since InitialNode is an ActivityNode your first answer has also been correct. Well, I still prefer the fork/join to make it explicit.

Comment: :) ok I come back to the first one, I trust you about the ActivityNode :)